# How to correctly access props in vue.js without passing through the div

Tags: vue.js

I have an api call being executed in the create hook in my vue root.  Then I have a component which is trying to use the data returned from the api call.

My question is very simple.  The example below works but is there a way to just have `<stage-execs></stage-execs>` without passing in job_execs = job_execs ?

I prefer the cleaner look of just using `<stage-execs></stage-execs>`

```
    <div id="vue-job">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row">
            <stage-execs v-bind:job_execs=job_execs></stage-execs>
        <br><br>
    </div>
    </div>


<script>
    Vue.component('stage-execs', {
        delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
        props: ['job_execs'],
        template: `
        <ul id="example-1">
          <h3>Stages</h3>
          <li v-for="item in this.job_execs">
            [[ item.build_id ]]
          </li>
        </ul>
        `,

var v_root = new Vue({
    delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
    el: '#vue-job',
    data: {
        job_execs: []
    },
    created() {
        url="http://{{ api_endpoint }}"
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(body => {
                for(i=0; i<body.length; i++){
                    this.job_execs.push({
                        'build_id': JSON.stringify(body[i].build_id),
                        'status': JSON.stringify(body[i].status.name),
                    })
                }
        })
        .catch( err => {
            console.log('Error Fetching:', url, err);
            return { 'failure': url, 'reason': err };
        });

    },
});
```

Comment: You can use vuex than the component access the information in the store. Also you can create an action that call your api.

Comment: If you are passing the whole result from the parent, why not get data from the compnent's mounted hook? so move the logic from the `vue-job` to `stage-execs`?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. The best you can do is lose the `v-bind`, so `:job_execs=job_execs`. (The `:` is a shorthand for v-bind)